# Access and insert a map of map of pair and int in C++

Tags: c++

For example I've got a map like this:

```
std::map<std::map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, int> >, int> mp;
```

How do I insert/access element into/in that map?
For inserting I've tried with

```
// using nested map 

std::map<pair<int, int>, pair<int, int> > mp2;
mp2.insert(make_pair(1,2), make_pair(3,4)); 
mp.insert(make_pair(mp2, 1));
```

For accessing the elements, I couldn't insert element into the map so I don't know if I did it right or wrong, but I think it is gonna be like this

```
mp[[1,2],[3,4]];
```

And the compiler throws a lot of errors . Some even navigate me to the implementation code of `std::map`, or to be more specific, the `stl_tree.h` thing.

What's wrong? I'm just a mere beginner so any help would be genuinely appreciated.

In addition, this is my homework. Basically I have to store coordinates like `(x,y)` and `(i,j)` to form a path into a container, and I've tried with vectors but I couldn't pass the time limit.

Comment: It'd help if you can show the minimal _complete_ code to reproduce, and the actual error(s). Otherwise no-one knows if their test code matches yours, or whether the're fixing the right error.

Comment: Am I reading this right, the *key* to your map is another map?

Comment: Using map as a key is going to be a pain. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What does the out map's `int` value mean? If you're trying to make a map from one set of coordinates to another and have the distance stored, you probably want something like `map<pair<int, int>, pair<pair<int, int>, int>>`. Or for much less confusion, create your own struct and have `map<Location, pair<Location, int>>`.

Comment: [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) does not have a comparator operator for itself. So you can't store it in another std::map without making sense of what you are identifying about the container. i.e., wrapping it in an identifiable/comparable class.

Comment: @lakeweb [Yes it does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_cmp). It doesn't mean it's a good idea to have it as a map key though :)

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I don't [see that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). What makes it comparable?

Comment: @lakeweb They are non-member functions, which you'll see at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Ok, I see that you can compare by size. I don't see that as very useful. Thanks. Now I see it compares the contents even before ++20. Comparing maps, crazy...

Comment: "_the compiler throws a lot of errors_" Always post at least the most frequent ones, in full.

Comment: @lakeweb It's not comparing maps by size, where did you read that? It's a lexicographical comparison, and it makes sense if comparing `std::pair<Key, Value>` makes sense. Or if you for some reason want to sort your maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reconsider your choice of data structure. Using `std::map` as a key to `std::map` will incur large overheads due to necessity of creating temporary keys to compare (when accessing outer map elements). It's highly unlikely that it will help you get through the time limit of yours.

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) requires a ready `std::pair<Key, Value>`, which means you need to wrap your arguments in one more `std::make_pair`

```
mp2.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair(1,2), std::make_pair(3,4)));
```

Or you can replace `insert` with [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

```
mp2.emplace(make_pair(1,2), make_pair(3,4));
```

To access elements you must construct a temporary map to be used as a key:

```
mp[{{{1,2},{3,4}}}]; //extra {} required
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OHS3Tkvddr3WHckU)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Yksisarvinen, you should reconsider using a map as a key to another map.

That being said, I guess you forgot an enclosing std::make_pair() at:

```
mp2.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1,2), make_pair(3,4)));
```

For accessing that, you'd need to do something like:

```
template <class K, class V>
std::map<K, V> make_map(std::pair<K, V>&& pair)
{
    return std::map<K, V> { pair };
}

mp[make_map(make_pair(make_pair(1 ,2), make_pair(3 , 4)))]
```

But beware that this is very inefficient!